# Embedded Linux and device driver development

Tags: linux, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I plan to learn embedded linux and writing linux device drivers.

I need a dev board where I can,

1. Build and boot it with a linux distribution.
2. Write drivers for peripherals in the board.
3. (In future) Possible port Android to it

Can you suggest a dev kit to help me with this? Cost is not a bar - I am already familiar with linux at user space, I am willingly to spend to get better at the other side.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) (TI OMAP)? The Beagleboard has an active community and a lot of example projects, including an [Android porting project](http://labs.embinux.org/index.php/Main_Page). They're a few versions of Android behind the present day, but that should provide a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new 25$ and 35$ option called **[Raspberry PI](http://www.raspberrypi.org)**.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://elinux.org/Android_on_OMAP
Google's Android on TI's ARM based OMAP SoCs / 2.6.23 Linux kernel

Answer (score 0):

I think [Armadeus project](http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) is for you. It is an open source project, that started in France and that is now expanding. The community is great and the number of peripherals is growing fast. Of course it is based on Linux.

A [small company](http://www.armadeus.com) is building the boards. They are based on ARM9 and now ARM11. In the boards you also have a Xilinx FPGA, that open the doors for exciting experiments.

Hope this helps.

JCLL

Answer (score 0):

Some cheap [mini2440](http://www.developmentboard.net/index.php/productlist/Development+board/ARM9/SAMSUNG/S3C2440) linux board sounds like a good start. It can also [run Android](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=mini2440+android).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have a [Virtual Development Board](http://www.armux.org/index.php/Virtual_Development_Board), that is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Check also the [OK6410](http://www.arm9board.net/sel/prddetail.aspx?id=348&pid=200) at http://www.arm9board.net, it is provided with Linux - 2.6.28 (2.6.36 in a quit near future) with all peripheral drivers and a basic Android system. You'll find it interesting and quit useful.